# How to reference ServiceBus in azure functions v2?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

This is not working (anymore): getting this error

> CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus'  run.csx(11,23) and CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' was not found

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus"

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

public static async Task Run(Message mySbMsg,  ILogger log)
```

any idea?
thank you

Comment: Does this post answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#r "..\\bin\\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll" 

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

public static async Task Run(Message mySbMsg,  ILogger log)
{
}
```

This assembly is not automatically added. take a look at following link for assemblies which are automatically added

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies